# Plotting complex roots and domain

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm trying to plot the roots of a complex equation, $p(z)=0$, and a domain, $D$, but have not found a clever way to cover general domains.

If we, e.g., take the equation $p(z)=5 z^3 + 9 z^2 - 25 z + 21 = 0$ with the domain $D:|z-1|<1$ an illustration can be given by

```
Clear[z]
equation = 5 z^3 + 9 z^2 - 25 z + 21 == 0;
domain = Disk[{1, 0}, 1];
roots = z /. NSolve[equation, z];
roots // TableForm
points = ReIm[roots];
p = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[points]}];
d = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Dashed], Opacity[0.1], Blue, domain}];
Show[d, p, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
```

The specification of $p(z)$ is quite good, but on the 3rd line, defining $D$, the way $D$ is specified is very limiting, as is the `EgdeForm[Dashed]` later on to indicate that the border of $D$ is not included in the domain. If $D$ where a more complex area, with the border included ("$...\le ...$"), this code would have to be modified in several places.

Is there are better way to plot complex roots and a domain (with or without the border)? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of *Mathematica* (like the one currently installed on the computer I am borrowing), I would have either done what you did, or use `RegionPlot[]` with appropriate conversions for domains more complicated than a disk.

Otherwise, the availability of `ComplexRegionPlot[]` and `ComplexListPlot[]` in version 12.1 makes things vastly easier:

```
Show[ComplexRegionPlot[Abs[z - 1] < 1, {z, -4 - 2 I, 3 + 2 I},
                       AspectRatio -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> Dashed],
     ComplexListPlot[z /. NSolve[5 z^3 + 9 z^2 - 25 z + 21 == 0, z],
                     PlotMarkers -> Style["■", Large], PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: disk and polynomial roots]

Note the use of `BoundaryStyle -> Dashed` to indicate that the region is open.